# Should we implement ignoring for tags with a similar suffix/prefix?

Tags: feature-request, tags, ignored-tags

The problem is about Ignored tag filter.

When someone marks his question with tag like `xcode4.5`, I see it, even if I ignore the `xcode` tag. There are tens of such tags - which differs in suffix. I don't want to add them all manually (using the 'Related tags' or some other list) - since, I'll have to track all newly added tags by myself (and manually add them, over and over again).

I suggest to implement some kind of tag inheritance. For example, when I ignore the `xcode` tag - all derived tags become ignored too (like, `xcode4.5`, `xcode4`, etc.).

The tag can inherit multiple tags - this will lighten the overall question tagging. You don't need to find and put all required tags for question already tagged with `facebook-c#-sdk`, since this tag inherits `facebook`, `c#`, etc.

Comment: I disagree that tag ignores should be automatically sorted by prefix and suffix. However, I'd like to see wildcards in ignores, such that I could block `ios*` for anything with prefix iOS. But tag inheritance? Disagree. Edit: whoa looks like this exists. Cool feature. Didn't know about it.

Comment: @Telthien: That would also block [tag:iostream].

Comment: Well, who cares about iostreams anyway!

Comment: "I'll have to track all newly added tags by myself." Er, can't you just add them to your ignore list as you come across them? I can see why this would be useful for favourites, but not for ignores. \*shrug\* Looks like they gave you the feature anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use wildcards `*` in your tag filter list, e.g. `xcode*` will ignore `xcode`, `xcode4.5` and so on. You can even add the wildcard at the beginning of the tag, so `*c#*` will also ignore `facebook-c#-sdk`. See: [Interesting and Ignored Tags Now Support Wildcards](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/interesting-and-ignored-tags-now-support-wildcards/)